# How to handle a Function utilizing a Stored Procedure from an array of data

Tags: php, mysql, function, stored-procedures

I have created a function that checks for quantities before saving the data into the sales table. This function works well on Single variables and the moment the post variables become multiple; it doesn’t work because they become an array. Is there a way in which I can handle an array utilizing the idea behind this function? The idea is for every set say ($productCode = 2) & ($quantity  = 10) function checks, then say ($productCode = 1) & ($quantity  = 20) until the last set.

```
        <?php
            //Checking quantity availability
            //Post variables
            //$productCode=$_POST['productCode'];
            //$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];

            //Equivalent variables
            $productCode = array(2, 1, 7, 2);
            $quantity    = array(10, 20, 30, 40);

            //My wild thought BUT no LUCK
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($productCode); $i++) {
                    $productCode=$productCode[$i];
                    $quantity=$quantity[$i];

            function CheckIfQuantityIsEnough ($productCode,$quantity)
            {
                try
                {
                    $QuantityIsEnough = false;
                    $pdoAssigned = new PDOConfig;
                    //Works perfectly well for one variable set
                    $resultQuantityIsEnough = $pdoAssigned->query("call sp_getStockQuantityCount($productCode,$quantity)");

                    if( $resultQuantityIsEnough->fetchColumn() >0) //the course has been assigned
                        {
                            $QuantityIsEnough = true;
                        }           
                    return $QuantityIsEnough;
                }

                catch (Exception $e) {
                throw $e;   
                }
            }
                }//End For statement


            //Check also if Quantity is enough for that
            if (CheckIfQuantityIsEnough ($productCode,$quantity) == false)
                {
                    $Feedback = "Quantity not enough for this product";

                }   
        ?>  

        //sp_getStockQuantityCount
        CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_getStockQuantityCount`(`vStockTypeID` INT, `vQuantity` DECIMAL(9,0))
        BEGIN
        declare vQuantityNow int;
        declare vQuantitySubtract int;

        set vQuantityNow=(select Quantity from stockquantitytbl where StockTypeID=vStockTypeID limit 1);
        set vQuantitySubtract=(vQuantityNow-vQuantity);

        select count(Quantity) 
        from stockquantitytbl
        where StockTypeID=vStockTypeID and vQuantitySubtract>=0;

        END
```

---------------Edit-----------------------

I have done away with the function and now just need to use the Stored Procedure as below:

```
            <?php
        //Array data
        //$productCode = array(2, 1, 7, 2);
        //$quantity    = array(10, 20, 30, 40);

        //Single set
        $productCode=7;
        $quantity=101;

        $sql="call sp_getStockQuantityCount($productCode,$quantity)";
        $result = $odb -> query($sql);
        if($result->rowcount() > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {

        $QuantityIsEnough = $row['Quantity'];

        if($QuantityIsEnough == 0)
                {
                    $Feedback = "Quantity not enough for this product";

                }       
                else
                {
                    //Insert sale record
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

One set works well, but the problem still remains on array data as explained above.

Comment: use sql directly rather than using stored procedures/functions and this will be easier.

Comment: can you post the error you might be getting?

Comment: what sort of checks do you need?

Comment: @danblack, checking quantity of products before inserting a new record.

Comment: @SandeepModak, it is not bringing any error.

Comment: @Ankit Singh, any leads on this problem?

Comment: @danblack, any ideas with the new Stored Procedure way?

Comment: SP suck. Your problem description is barely comprehensible now. Just because this class assignment insists on a SP doesn't mean its sane or has any value. If you can't solve the problem in SQL putting in a SP doesn't make it more solveable.